# DNN 8 unable to install extension

Tags: dotnetnuke

I created my module and it used to work properly but after uninstalling I get this error:

```
AbsoluteURL:/Default.aspx

DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke

ExceptionGUID:0fe3f4ae-48e2-4d82-818b-b4e0cb639672

AssemblyVersion:8.0.3

PortalId:0

UserId:95

TabId:36

RawUrl:/Host/Extensions/tabid/36/ctl/Install/rtab/36/portalid/0/language/en-US/Default.aspx?popUp=true

Referrer:http://localhost/Host/Extensions/tabid/36/ctl/Install/rtab/36/portalid/0/language/en-US/Default.aspx?popUp=true

UserAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.146 Safari/537.36

ExceptionHash:Lv0u7/ELvn42FpwfPTPUTQ==

Message:The system cannot find the file specified.

StackTrace:

InnerMessage:The system cannot find the file specified.

InnerStackTrace:

   at SchwabenCode.QuickIO.Internal.InternalQuickIOCommon.NativeExceptionMapping(String path, Int32 errorCode)
   at SchwabenCode.QuickIO.QuickIOFile.OpenFileStream(QuickIOPathInfo pathInfo, FileAccess fileAccess, FileMode fileOption, FileShare shareMode, Int32 buffer)
   at SchwabenCode.QuickIO.QuickIOFile.OpenText(QuickIOPathInfo pathInfo)
   at DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.FileSystemUtils.ReadFile(String filePath)
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installers.PackageInstaller.ReadTextFromFile(String source)
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installers.PackageInstaller.ReadManifest(XPathNavigator manifestNav)
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installers.PackageInstaller..ctor(String packageManifest, InstallerInfo info)
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installer.ProcessPackages(XPathNavigator rootNav)
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installer.ReadManifest(Boolean deleteTemp)
   at DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Extensions.Install.wizInstall_NextButtonClick(Object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnNextButtonClick(WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
Source:

FileName:

FileLineNumber:0

FileColumnNumber:0

Method:
```

Do you know why this would happen? I tried to install it several times. I am going crazy over this error. I am using DNN 8. The above is what I see in Event viewer. If any more details is needed please let me know.

Comment: it seems the uninstall removed more that it should have. Can you add the files from the module manually to the `bin` and `/DesktopModules/YourModule` and see what happens. But try to find out which file is missing.

Comment: Thanks the license.txt file was missing. After I put it back it worked as normal.

Answer (score 0):

When an install happens, it extracts the zip file to a temporary location before processing it using the manifest file (.dnn).

Ensure the following:

1. Permissions are set correctly to allow the service account running DNN To write to a temporary location
2. Ensure the contents of your manifest file matches the contents of your module zip install file